# qt Qmake generating pkgconfig for a project

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake, pkg-config

I have been told that it is possible to generate a pkg-config file through qmake, but I have no idea how to do it. I have been looking online for a while, and it seems as though it is something you just have to know how to do. Can someone give me an example, or point me to some sort of guide/tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150218094344/http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_pkg-config_with_qmake) what you are looking for?

To generate pkg-config using qmake you have to add to (modify) your project file (*.pro file):

```
unix {
    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += <pc_file_without_extension>
}
```

Comment: Can you at least expand on the linked text? If the link breaks, we have no choice but to remove this answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to *generate* a .pc file (in contrast to simply use pkg-config to find dependencies, which is well supported by qmake), you might be interested in the following.  Obviously, creating .pc files is a less visible, but existing feature of QMake.  You want to use `CONFIG += create_pc`, which depends on `create_prl`.  If you don't want to install the .prl file, use `no_install_prl`, too.  Overall, this gives you:

```
CONFIG += create_pc create_prl no_install_prl

QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_NAME = VigraQt
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_DESCRIPTION = Qt4 bindings for the VIGRA library
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_PREFIX = $$INSTALLBASE
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR = $$target.path
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_INCDIR = $$headers.path
QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_VERSION = $$VERSION
```

This is what I came up with for [VigraQt](http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/vigraqt/).  There's also `QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_DESTDIR`, which you may use to specify the location of the .pc files within the source directory.  Finally, there are `QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_VARIABLES`, `QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES`, and `QMAKE_PKGCONFIG_CFLAGS` in addition to the above.

(There is also `create_libtool` for .la files, which also depends on the .prl files.)